# What's the WPF equivalent of a Winform _Paint event

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, onrender

I have experience with WinForms and frequently used the _Paint event for drawing. While exploring WPF, I came across the OnRender method and heard that it might be the equivalent for custom drawing in WPF.

I would like to confirm if the OnRender method is indeed the real equivalent to the _Paint event in WinForms for drawing in WPF. Additionally, I'm would like to know if using the OnRender method is the most efficient way to perform custom drawing in terms of rendering speed and performance.

Comment: You should read [WPF Graphics Rendering Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8), especially the section [Visual Rendering Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/wpf-graphics-rendering-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#visual-rendering-behavior) to understand the diference between GDIs *immediate mode* graphics and the *retained mode* graphics system in WPF.

Comment: The OnRender method is one way to implement custom drawing, but it is not a "*real equivalent*" of the Paint event.

Comment: I suspect you can probably achieve your aim in a better way than in OnRender. Depends what you want to do though.